# shell script to find the day and time and execute next steps[Redhat6.7]

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, rhel

I have a scenario where I need to execute a shell script according to the day it is.
here is the code:

```
cd /home/test/check
perl test.pl check.ini parameters
```

I want to execute this two lines only if the day is not a Thursday if the day is thursday it should not execute the following lines. how can i achieve the same I am quite new to shell scripts any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date "+%u"` to get a numeric day of week  (1 is Monday).

```
if [ $(date "+%u") !=  "4" ]; then
   cd /home/test/check
   perl test.pl check.ini parameters
fi
```

Comment: when i execute on my terminal it gives error at fi

Comment: If you are not using it in a script separate the commands with `;`, eg. `if ... ; then cmd1; cmd2; ... ; fi`.

Comment: I tried the same but still same error can you give an example of what exactly u meant

Comment: Isn't `if [ $(date "+%u") !=  "4" ]; then cd /home/test/check; perl test.pl check.ini parameters; fi` what you used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crontab` to execute scripts at a certain time.
Edit crontab using `crontab -e`

```
 # Use the hash sign to prefix a comment
    # +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
    # |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
    # |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
    # |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
    # |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
    # |  |  |  |  |
    # *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

e.g, this runs everyday at 11:59 am except for on Thursday. :

```
59 11 * * 1,2,3,5,6,7 nohup /usr/local/bin/perl  /home/test/check/perl.pl check parameters > /tmp/script.log 2>&1
```

Comment: this gives an error : bash11 command not found

Comment: can you try the edited answer, i added the absolute path to the perl binary. If this works, that means you forgot the add the shebang line in your perl code.

Comment: I would require it to run on a shell so do you think crontab is good idea?
I have a jenkins job which builds and then in step execute shell i should check the above script. will it work?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have enough `jenkins` knowledge to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

This runs 6 days out of the week and is fairly self-documenting. Replace || with && if you want to run just 1 day, on Thursday.

```
cd /home/test/check
date | egrep '^Thu ' || perl test.pl check.ini parameters
```